# Undefined variable: total in routes/web.php LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, variables, undefined

I have a problem passing the variable `hours` from the controller to the blade template. What is wrong?

**web.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/hours', 'easyController@hours');
//widok dodawania godzin
Route::get('/hours/add', 'easyController@add');
//zapisywanie do bazy danych
Route::post('/hours', 'easyController@save');
//usuwanie z bazy danych
Route::delete('/hours/{id}', 'easyController@delete');
//suma czasu pracy z bazy
Route::get('/hours', function(){
    return view('hours', ['total' => $total]);
});
```

**Control Method:**

```
public function pass(){
        $total = DB::table('hours')->select(DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC('total'))) as suma"))->value('suma');
        return view('hours', ['total' => $total]);
    }
```

**hours.blade.php:**

```
<p>{{$total}}</p>
```

Comment: Hello, please read the **Non-English Question Policy** https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/.
Sack Overflow encourages you to make an attempt to either seek help from someone or to use a translator to convert your question into English if you can before posting.

Comment: @ryantxr too quick to close this question, it was salvageable with a minor edit as per the guidelines and a bit unfair towards a new user without pointing them towards any guidance

Answer (score 0):

You should either change your web.php route file to

```
Route::get('/hours', function(){
    $total = DB::table('hours')->select(DB::raw("SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC('total'))) as suma"))->value('suma');
    return view('hours', ['total' => $total]);
});
```

or better to

```
Route::get('/hours', 'easyController@pass');
```